# Why my Contact.dart isn't running? (Flutter, Dart, Vs Code)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout

The Code is 100% okay & also haven't any error, But when ever I'm trying to run the code suddenly the "silver.dart" file opened and the result didn't showed.
why this line from Silver.dart is showed over & over again?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/inVsw.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have an exception but it's not showing because you told VSCode to add a breakpoint at exceptions.

Do you see "Breakpoints" -> "Uncaught Exception" at the bottom left of your screen? Uncheck that, run again, and the exception should appear as usual if any.